# Definition of limits of a function in general.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. I will begin with some definitions:

1. A sequence $(x_n)$ *converges* to $x\in X$, denoted by $x_n\to x$, if every neighborhood of $x$ contains $x_n$ for sufficient large $n.$
2. Let $f: X\to Y$ be a function between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. We say $f(x)\to y_0$ as $x\to x_0$ if for every sequence $(x_n)\to x_0$ in $X$ disjoint from $x_0$(so that $x_n$ is never $x_0$ for all $n$) the sequence $f(x_n)\to y_0.$

In a Hausdorff space $X$ every convergent sequence has a unique limit. We write $\lim\limits_X x_n= x$ in this case. Let $f: X\to Y$ as in 2. with $Y$ Hausdorff. To ensure function limit $y_0$ at $x_0$ to be unique(if exists) we must impose the condition below:

> $(i)$ For some sequence $(x_n)$ disjoint from $x_0$ in $X$, $(x_n)\to x_0$.

The above condition follows from two stronger conditions:

> $(ii)$ $x_0$ is not an isolate point.
>
> $(iii)$ $x_0$ has a countable neighborhood base.

**My first question: does $(i)$ imply $(iii)$?**

Suppose that condition $(i)$ holds and denote the limit by $\lim_{x\to x_0, X\to Y} f(x)$ or when there's no confusion, $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$. Of course we should hope the two following results hold:

> Hypothesis 1. $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
>
> Hypothesis 2. $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=y_0$ if and only if for every open neighborhood $U_{y_0}$ of $y_0$ there is an open neighborhood $U_{x_0}$ of $x_0$ such that $f(U_{x_0}-\{x_0\})\subset U_{y_0}$.

Hypothesis 1. is true if $(iii)$ holds, that is, $x_0$ has a countable neighborhood base. Hypothesis 2. should require that $y_0$ has a countable neighborhood base.

**Question 2.(proof verification)** Does Hypothesis 1 and 2 hold by assuming $x_0$ has a countable neighborhood base and $y_0$ has a countable neighborhood base, respectively?

Comment: "In a Hausdorff space every sequence converges to a unique limit" is not correct. Every **convergent** sequence has a unique limit, but if $X$ has more than one point, then not every sequence converges (e.g., take a sequence that alternates between two distinct points).

Comment: Even in a compact Hausdorff space with uncountably many points and no isolated points, it may be that the only convergent countable sequences are eventually constant sequences.

Comment: "$y_0$ has a neighbourhood base" is a void condition. $\{O \in \mathcal{T}: y_0 \in O\}$ is always a neighbourhood base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$st question.  No.
$[0,\omega_1] \cup \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{Z}, n > 0\}$ 
with the base
$\{U, V \cup W_n, \{1/n\}: n \in \mathbb{Z}, n > 0,  
U,V \text{ open within [0,\omega_1] }, \omega_1 \notin U, 
\omega_1 \in V\}$
where $W_n = \{ 0, 1/k : k \in \mathbb{Z}, k > 0, k \leq n\}  $
provides a counterexample.

This is the space $[0,\omega_1] \cup \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{Z}, n > 0\}$
where $0$ is identified with $\omega_1$.